# Understanding contains method of Java HashSet

Tags: java, contains, hashset

Newbie question about java HashSet

```
Set<User> s = new HashSet<User>();
User u = new User();
u.setName("name1");
s.add(u);
u.setName("name3");
System.out.println(s.contains(u));
```

Can someone explain why this code output false ? Moreover this code does not even call equals method of User. But according to the sources of HashSet and HashMap it have to call it.  Method equals of User simply calls equals on user's name. Method hashCode return hashCode of user's name

Comment: To quote Jon Skeet "Objects in hashsets should either be immutable, or you need to exercise discipline in not changing them after they've been used in a hashset (or hashmap)." - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718009/mutable-objects-and-hashcode

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the hash code method is based on the `name` field, and you then change it after adding the object, then the second `contains` check will use the new hash value, and won't find the object you were looking for. This is because `HashSet`s first search by hash code, so they won't bother calling `equals` if that search fails.

The only way this would work is if you *hadn't* overridden `equals` (and so the default reference equality was used) *and* you got lucky and the hash codes of the two objects were equal. But this is a *really* unlikely scenario, and you shouldn't rely on it.

In general, you should *never* update an object after you have added it to a `HashSet` if that change will also change its hashcode.

Comment: so it's a copy of u added in the hashset ? Otherwise I'd think the object in nameset would have name3 aswell

Answer (score 11):

Since your new `User` has a different hashcode, the HashSet knows that it isn't equal.

HashSets store their items according to  their hashcodes.
The HashSet will only call `equals` if it finds an item with the same hashcode, to make sure that the two items are actually equal (as opposed to a hash collision)

Comment: Indeed it calls equals only if hashCode are equal. This means that if i update User, which change it hashCode, the nested array that contains Entry associated with their hashCodes would not be updated. So iterating over this array would not return entry with same hashCode. Should work if hashCode always return 0 )

Comment: Correct.  In general, it is a bad idea to put mutable objects in a HashSet.  If you make `hashCode()` return `0`, you will lose all of the performance benefits of the HashSet, and you'll end up with the  slowest collection you can possibly get.

Comment: I know, this is just an example

Comment: I believe this should be the accepted answer. It's worth noting that the javadoc for `HashSet.contains()` does not say anything about equals being applied only after the check for hashcode.