# using HashSet with overridden .equals()

Tags: java, java-8, hashset

I'm trying to use `HashSet` in java 8 with an overridden `.equals()` method.  Here's a example of the code I'm using:

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Test{
    String id;
    int a;

    public Test (String i, int a){
            this.id = i;
            this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if (obj instanceof Test){
            if (((Test)obj).id == this.id){
                    return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args){
        HashSet<Test> set = new HashSet<Test>();

        Test a = new Test("hello", 1);
        Test b = new Test("hello", 2);

        System.out.println("equals?\t\t" + a.equals(b));

        set.add(a);

        System.out.println("contains b?\t" + set.contains(b));
        System.out.println("contains a?\t" + set.contains(a));

        System.out.println("specific?\t" + (b == null ? a == null : b.equals(a)));

    }

}
```

Here's the output:

```
equals?         true
contains b?     false
contains a?     true
specific?       true
```

As you can see, `.equals()` passes as expected, but `contains()` does not behave as I would expect.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains-java.lang.Object-), `contains()` should pass "if and only if this set contains an element e such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`".  I ran that exact code and it passes, so why does `contains()` still fail?

Comment: The contains logic is being inherited from the Collections type. Hashset uses the hashcode to determine uniqueness.

Comment: then why does the documentation say it uses equals?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026564/understanding-contains-method-of-java-hashset

Comment: Also the underlying container for HashSet is HashMap. The objects are stored as keys within the HashMap. The contains method calls the contains key, which uses the hashcode to find the index of the map and then uses the equals of the object. If the hashcode isn't matching, then it won't find the index.

Comment: You override equals() but not hashCode() in Test.  This leads to trouble when used as keys in hash-based collections, which is exactly the trouble you're having now.