# Do java objects used as hash keys need to be 'fully' immutable?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode

If **`hashCode()`** calculation **uses immutable fields** and `equals()` uses all the fields would it be a problem when the class is used as a hash key? E.g.

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class Car {
    protected final long vin;
    protected String state;
    protected String plateNumber;

    public Car( long v, String s, String p ) {
        vin = v; state = s; plateNumber = p;
    }


    public void move( String s, String p ) {
        state = s; plateNumber = p;
    }


    public int hashCode() {
        return (int)( vin % Integer.MAX_VALUE );
    }


    public boolean equals( Object other ) {
        if (this == other) return true;
        else if (!(other instanceof Car)) return false;
        Car otherCar = (Car) other;
        return vin == otherCar.vin
                && Objects.equals( state, otherCar.state )
                && Objects.equals( plateNumber, otherCar.plateNumber );
    }
}
```

And move() is called on a car object after it is inserted into a hashset, possible via a reference kept elsewhere.

I am not after performance issues here. Only correctness.

I have read [java hashCode contact](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()), few answers on SO including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718009/mutable-objects-and-hashcode) by venerable Jon Skeet and [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05273/#N10172) from big blue. I feel that the last link gives the best explanation and imply that above code is correct.

**Edit**

Conclusion:
This class satisfy constraints placed on ‘equals()’ and ‘hashCode()’ in java. However it violates restrictions additional requirements placed on ‘equals()’ when used as keys in collections, hashed or not.
The additional requirement is that ‘equals()’ need to be consistent as long as the object is a key.
See the counter example by Louis Wasserman and the reference provided by Douglas below.

Few clarifications:

A) This class satisfy java object level constraints:

1. ( carA == carB ) implies ( carA.hashCode() == carB.hashCode() )
2. ( carA.hashCode() != carB.hashCode() )  implies ( carA != carB )
3. equals() need to be reflexive, symmetric, transitive.
4. hashCode() need to be consistent. i.e. Cannot change for an object during its lifetime.
5. equals() need to be consistent *as long as neither object is modified*.

Note that the reverse of ‘1.’ and ‘2.’ are not necessary. And the class above satisfies all the conditions.
Also java docs mention *"equals() … implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects*", but not sure if that is compulsory.

B) As for performance, the increment in collision avoidance probability decrease with each successive member variable we combine. Usually few well chosen member variables is sufficient.

Comment: If equals and hashcode are inconsistent with each other then you have bigger problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct if you never, ever call `move` after the `Car` is in the map.  Otherwise it's wrong.  Both `hashCode` *and* `equals` have to stay consistent after a key is in the map.

Comment: Sorry, just edited the question. Could you explain what would cause a problem or violate the language requirements? Thanks.

Comment: Your statement is kind of broad. Yes, in general it's wrong, but in almost all cases it works, depending on the use-case we look at. Let's assume a `HashMap` and we use `c` an instance of `Car` as key for the map (whatever the associated value will be). If `c` changes, the `HashMap` will still work as expected. If I pass in `something` that satisfies `something.equals(c)` (with the changed `c`) it will find the associated value in the `HashMap`, because the `hashCode` of `c` did not change and the `equals` is executed on demand by the `HashMap` implementation.

Comment: Can you give an example when map'll start work bad after calling move ? Right now I see that it's legal to call move, and key will be reachable. Yeah, it's better to use immutable or effectively immutable objects, but it's not the must, when hashcode doesn't use mutable fields or maybe I don't understand something.

Comment: Two keys that started out not equal can become equal after you call `move`.  This violates the `HashMap` contract that no two keys are the same in the map.

Comment: Note that as a result, the second occurrence of the key "disappears" from the map: you can't access it with `get`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks, excellent point, I didn't think of that. With 'VIN' I assumed 'VIN's are 'unique' and that two cars with the same VIN will not be used as keys. Agree that in that case my 'equals()' is overkill.

Answer (score 2):

When considering only the `hashCode` and `equals` contracts, you are correct that this implementation satisfies their requirements. `hashCode` using a strict subset of the fields that `equals` uses is sufficient to guarantee that `a.equals(b)` implies `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()` as required.

However, things change when you bring in `Map`. From the [`Map` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), "The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is a key in the map."

After you call `move` on a `Car` that is a key in a `Map`, the behavior of that `Map` is now unspecified. In many cases it will in practice still work the way you want it to, but bizarre things could happen in ways that are hard to predict. While it would technically be valid for the `Map` to spontaneously empty itself or switch all lookups to use a random number generator, a more likely scenario might go like this:

`Car car1 = ...
Car car2 = ... // a copy of car1
Map<Car, String> map1 = ...
map1.put(car1, "value");
assert map1.get(car2).equals("value"); // true
car1.move(...);
assert map1.get(car2).equals("value"); // NullPointerException on the equals call, car2 is no longer found`

Notice that neither `car2` nor the `Map` were changed themselves in any way, but the mapping of `car2` changed (or rather, disappeared) anyway. This behavior is not officially specified, but I would guess most `Map` implementations do behave this way.

Comment: When you say `Car car2 = ... // a copy of car1`, do you mean `Car car2 = car1`?

Comment: @Arkadiy No, that would make `car2` just a reference to the same object. I mean that `car2` is a new, separate, instance of `Car` that just so happens to satisfy the condition `car1.equals(car2)`.

Answer (score 1):

You may mutate your key candidates as much as you want, **before or after (not during) they are used as keys**. 
In practice, it is very hard to enforce this rule. If you mutate objects you do not have a control if somebody uses them as keys or not.

Immutability for keys is just easier, removes source of subtle, hard-to-find bugs and just work better for key.

In your case I see no correctness issues. But why you ever bother not to include all fields in hashcode?

Answer (score 1):

Hash works by putting items into "buckets". Each bucket is calculated by the `hashcode`. After finding the bucket then the search continues comparing each item one by one using `equals`.

For example:

- During insertion: an object whose id is 100 is placed in bucket 5 (the hashcode calculated 5).
- During retrieval: you ask the hashmap to find the item 100. If the hash calculates 7 now then the algorithm will search for your object in bucket 7 but your object will never be found as it is dwelling in bucket 5.

In summary: the hash code and the actual key work together. The former is used to know in which bucket the item should be. The latter is used by the `equals` comparison seeking the actual item to return.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: it should be OK, but prepare for bizarre behavior.

Longer answer: when you change fields that participate in equals() on a key, the value keyed by that key will no longer be found.

Still longer answer: this looks as X/Y problem: you're asking about X, but you really need X to accomplish Y. Maybe you should ask about Y?

The car in your case is uniquely identified by `vin`. A car equals to itself. But, a car can be registered in different states. Maybe the answer is to have a Registration object (or a few of them) attached to the car? And then you can separate `car.equals()` from `registration.equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

When your `hashCode()` implementation uses only limited number of fields (vs `equals`) you're reducing performance of almost any algorithm/data structure that uses hashing: `HashMap`, `HashSet` etc. You're increasing collision probability - it's the situation when two different objects (`equals` return false) have the same hash value.

Comment: not strictly true. Colision probability depends on number of unique hashcode values. It is possible that, even having hashcode that depends on single field, it will be unique enough. Example- hashcode based on unique Id (that comes from database sequence).

Comment: @BartoszBilicki In your example with unique ID why would you use any other fields in `equals` method?

Comment: In case described in my comment I would make both equals and hashcode depend only on that uniqueID. But that uniqueID must be immutable, and must be provided when you create object (by ctor/factory method). That is one of the ways of solve identity issues for entities with Hibernate/JPA.

Comment: @BartoszBilicki In my answer I'm talking about the situation when in hashCode one uses a subset of fields used in equals.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: No.

Long answer:

Fully immutability is not neccessary. BUT:

Equals must only depend on immutable values. Hashcode must depend on immutable values either a constant or a subset of the values used in equals or all values used in equals. Values that are not mentioned within equals mustn't be part of hashcode.

If you mutate values equals and hashcode rely on it is likely that you do not find your objects again in a hash based datastructure. Look at this:

```
public class Test {


    private static class TestObject {
        private String s;

        public TestObject(String s) {
            super();
            this.s = s;
        }

        public void setS(String s) {
            this.s = s;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            boolean equals = false;
            if (obj instanceof TestObject) {
                TestObject that = (TestObject) obj;
                equals = this.s.equals(that.s);
            }
            return equals;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return this.s.hashCode();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestObject a1 = new TestObject("A");
        TestObject a2 = new TestObject("A");

        System.out.println(a1.equals(a2)); // true

        HashMap<TestObject, Object> hashSet = new HashMap<>(); // hash based datastructure

        hashSet.put(a1, new Object());

        System.out.println(hashSet.containsKey(a1)); // true

        a1.setS("A*");

        System.out.println(hashSet.containsKey(a1)); // false !!! // Object is not found as the hashcode used initially before mutation was used to determine the hash bucket

        a2.setS("A*");

        System.out.println(hashSet.containsKey(a2)); // false !!! Because a1 is in wrong hash bucket ...

        System.out.println(a1.equals(a2)); // ... even if the objects are equals

    }

}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the OP's question . In the question, OP states that `hashCode()` only depends on immutable fields. In your example, `hasCode()` uses `s` which is mutated.

Comment: I did exactly answer the question. I stated that there is no problem with his approach to use objects that have hashcode equals override and relying on immutable values. Then I sharpened the rules under which it would never cause a problem (hashcode must be constant or rely on values used in equals, equals must rely on immutable values). Finally I showed an example where I violate the rules to show the mechanics.

Comment: AND I now adapted my answer so that the object is a key of a hash map...

Comment: the only requirement for hashCode()/equals() is that hashCode returns same value when equals==true. There is no requirement that hashCode should use exactly the same fields as equals(). hashCode can use a proper subset of fields. In fact, hashCode can use an EMPTY subset of fields - it's terrible for performance, but it does not break the invariant.

Comment: Another issue: your sample code demonstrates a problem, but it's not a problem relevant to OP's question. You show that mutable fields must not be used in hashCode. But the OP is not trying to do that.